# How do I make a button and an input stay on the same line inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Given:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="dv">
            <button id="bt" type="button">X</button>
            <input id="num" type="number" value="1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="aaa"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/ZZFc5/1/

[image]

But, if I resize the window, then I get this:

[image]

What I want to achieve is that:

1. All the controls stay on the same line, even when the window is resized.
2. The input controls occupy all the available space (the button size can be made constant).
3. When the window is resized, the input controls are resized as well.
4. The X button must share the first cell with the input control.
5. No absolute sizes should be used, except for the X button.

This should be simple, but I just cannot get my head around it.

Please, share your wisdom.

**EDIT**

If possible, I would like to avoid specifying absolute values (like pixels) for all, but the X button, which may be given absolute width and height.

**EDIT2**

Added the 5th constraint.

Comment: You can always give your table a minimun width. (`min-width: 300px;`)

Comment: This value is font dependent, isn't it? If possible, I prefer not using absolute values for anything but the button.

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data. Why must you use this odd table structure in your HTML?

Comment: This is the best I could come up when trying to design an invoice page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can stick a width on the table like `100%`, then you can try something like the following.

I modified your HTML to add an id to the text field; nothing more.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="dv">
                <button id="bt" type="button">X</button>
                <input id="num" type="number" value="1"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="txt" type="text" value="aaa"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
tr td {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

#bt {
    width: 25px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

button {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#num {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25px;
    right: 0;
}

#txt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See [the JSFiddle I forked from yours](http://jsfiddle.net/f37xJ/2/).

Basically I set the size of the button to 25px, and then set the widths of each of the `<td>`s to 50% of the table width. Then I used absolute positioning to tell the textfield and input field to take up all of the available horizontal room and nothing else. The components will therefore resize when you resize the window, but will never "drop" onto a second row.
​

Comment: Thanks. One question though - why `tr td` and not just `td`?

Comment: No reason. I was originally trying to style `tr` but then remembered there are limitations on styling that tag so I switched to `td`. It's a slightly more specific selector, but it will work the same.

Answer (score 3):

> < nobr > is your friend here

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="dv">
          <nobr>
            <button id="bt" type="button">X</button>
            <input id="num" type="number" value="1"/>
          </nobr>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="aaa"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mXSgd/

For actual resizable form elements this might help:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/anchoring.html

or this:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-resizeable-textboxes

Comment: Thanks, but condition 3 does not hold - the inputs do not resize.

Comment: resizable elements? Sounds like js :)

Comment: +1 for the links. I prefer to wait a bit and see if anyone comes up with a purely css solution...

Answer (score 1):

In that vein, you could set a min-width to the container (or children), which in this instance is the table, see below.  Or reset the table in percents and make it flexible yet controlled.

```
<table style="min-width:300px">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/ZZFc5/1/

You could ditch the table approach and use css floats

Answer (score 0):

Set stylesheet on table may can help you.

> table {width: 200px;} 
>   table tr td {width: 30%;}

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZFc5/2/

Comment: I do not want to pin the table size to any absolute value, because one value may be looking good for one font, but bad for another. The only absolute size that can be used is for the X button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="bt" type="button">X</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="num" type="number" value="1"/>
                </td>                    
              </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="aaa"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

put those elements in another table in side your cell